# Fatal error: Enum case value must be compile-time evaluatable

Tags: php, php-8

I'm trying to include a constant in a Enum value but I get the fatal error `Enum case value must be compile-time evaluatable` (here's the code) :

```
const PARENT = 'parent';
enum MyEnum:string
{
    case firstChild = PARENT . '_child1';
    case secondChild = PARENT . '_child2';
    
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error, because the value of a constant can't change.
I have already Google the error but I have found nothing.
Any idea?

Comment: `Enums are similar to classes, and share the same namespaces as classes, interfaces, and traits. They are also autoloadable the same way.` This means that the case must be simple values, not something to be compiled at runtime. A const can't change, but it has to evaluate `PARENT . '_child1'`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php - `Equivalent values must be literals or literal expressions. Constants and constant expressions are not supported. That is, 1 + 1 is allowed, but 1 + SOME_CONST is not.`

Comment: @aynber the second statement is correct. The first one is irrelevant - constants are compile-time-evaluable, it's just not supported. Respectivelly, those [defined with `const`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php): `constants defined using the const keyword must be declared at the top-level scope because they are defined at compile-time`. They still act as runtime, and that's the core issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction between "compile-time" and "run-time" in PHP is not always obvious, because we don't explicitly "build" a PHP project like we would with a language like C or Java. The rules of what happens when are also subtle, and governed partly by historical features of the language.

In this case, it *looks like* the constant `PARENT` would be available when the definition of `MyEnum` was being processed; but that's not *quite* how it works.

If we do the same thing with a normal class, we can try to see this in action:

```php
class Foo {
    const EXAMPLE = OTHER_CONST;
}
var_dump(class_exists('Foo'));
echo Foo::EXAMPLE;
```

If you run that code on its own, you will see that the class is *compiled* without the constant it references actually being available, and the `class_exists` call succeeds. Only when you try to actually access `Foo::EXAMPLE` does PHP try to evaluate the global constant it refers to, and gives an error (or, in older versions, a Notice or Warning).

That allows things to load "in the wrong order" - either of these will succeed, even though one defines the constant "before" the class, and one "after" it:

```php
define('OTHER_CONST', 'some value');
class Foo {
    const EXAMPLE = OTHER_CONST;
}
var_dump(class_exists('Foo'));
echo Foo::EXAMPLE;
```

or:

```php
class Foo {
    const EXAMPLE = OTHER_CONST;
}
var_dump(class_exists('Foo'));
define('OTHER_CONST', 'some value');
echo Foo::EXAMPLE;
```

I've used `define` here to make it more obvious that this is run-time code; it could equally be a `const` line in a different PHP file being included, for instance.

The key here is that even if the constant definition appears before the class definition, it's not actually evaluated when the class definition is being compiled. It is "evaluated at run-time" when the class constant is first referenced.

Coming back to your enum example, the error makes a bit more sense: although the constant definition happens to appear first in the file, uses of it are not "evaluated at compile time". Unlike class constants, the values of backed enum cases are always calculated while the enum is being compiled, so can't contain references to things that won't exist until run-time, which unfortunately includes global constants.

However, a small modification *does* work:

```
class Something
{
    const PARENT = 'parent';
}
enum MyEnum:string
{
    case firstChild = Something::PARENT . '_child1';
    case secondChild = Something::PARENT . '_child2';
    
}
```

This works because in this case the class constant itself can be evaluated at compile-time, and will then be available when the enum definition is compiled.

To bring things full-circle, this will *not* work:

```php
const GRAND_PARENT = 'parent';

class Something
{
    const PARENT = GRAND_PARENT;
}
enum MyEnum:string
{
    case firstChild = Something::PARENT . '_child1';
    case secondChild = Something::PARENT . '_child2';
    
}
var_dump(class_exists('MyEnum'));
echo MyEnum::firstChild->value;
```

Here, the global constant is considered a run-time value, so the class constant is deferred until run-time; when the enum is compiled, it tries to fetch the class constant's value but can't, so gives an error.

Comment: @aym I have rejected your proposed edit to add a shouty warning at the top of this answer. There are multiple examples in this answer, and as far as I can see, none has changed behaviour. Here are the three working examples, running in multiple versions of PHP: https://3v4l.org/V7GEp https://3v4l.org/bjPor https://3v4l.org/5A41I Feel free to leave a comment here regarding what behaviour you think has been "fixed".